# c# how to reverse string and then undo the reverse in the same method

Tags: c#, string

Hi I have a simple question how to reverse a string and then undo the reversal within the same method in C#. I know there's many ways to reverse a string but I'm currently using the Array.Reverse method.
Sample code:

```
    static void ReverseString()
    {
        const string name = "Hello World";
        var mystring = name.ToCharArray();

        Array.Reverse(mystring);
        Console.WriteLine(new string(mystring));
    }
```

So I want to take the output "dlroW olleH" and pass it into another array.reverse to get back "Hello World" If it's not possible to do within the same method then I would like an example of how to pass that output "dlroW olleH" into a new method so it can be reversed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: strings are immutable in C# (unless you will play with unsafe), so your original string will not change.

Comment: I don't understand the problem.. Just call it the reversal again?

Comment: I'm newer to development so it's hard for me to describe the problem. The code above works but I want to take the output I get on the console "dlroW olleH" and reverse it back to "Hello World". I need assistance with syntax on how to do this, first how do I store the output value from the console  "dlroW olleH"? Then how do I pass this new stored value into another Array.Reverse so I can get the output "Hello World" back. It seems silly but in my case it actually has an application where I can only parse my original string when it's reversed so after it's parsed I need to undo the reverse.

Comment: `public static string() ReverseString(string value) => value == null ? null : string.Concat(value.Reverse());` then `Console.WriteLine(ReverseString("Hello World"));` and `Console.WriteLine(ReverseString(ReverseString("Hello World")));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... how do I store the output value from the console "dlroW olleH"? Then
> how do I pass this new stored value into another Array.Reverse

I believe what you're looking for is to convert your `ReverseString()` method, into a FUNCTION.  Change the return type from `void` to `string` so you can store the reversal back in `Main()`.  Then you can pass that back in, and store the output, which should be the original string again.

All together, that'd look like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string name = "Hello World";
    Console.WriteLine("Original: " + name);

    string name2 = ReverseString(name);
    Console.WriteLine("Reversed: " + name2);

    string name3 = ReverseString(name2);
    Console.WriteLine("Reversed again: " + name3);

    Console.Write("Press Enter to Quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

static string ReverseString(string input)
{
    var inputArray = input.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(inputArray);
    return new string(inputArray);
}
```

Output:

```
Original: Hello World
Reversed: dlroW olleH
Reversed again: Hello World
Press Enter to Quit
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing stopping you from calling `Array.Reverse()` a 2nd time..

```
static void ReverseString()
{
    const string name = "Hello World";
    var mystring = name.ToCharArray();

    Array.Reverse(mystring);
    Array.Reverse(mystring);
    Console.WriteLine(new string(mystring));
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PfHRni

Comment: Thank you for your response!

Comment: I'm newer to development so it's hard for me to describe the problem. The code above works but I want to take the output I get on the console "dlroW olleH" and reverse it back to "Hello World". I need assistance with syntax on how to do this, first how do I store the output value from the console "dlroW olleH"? Then how do I pass this new stored value into another Array.Reverse so I can get the output "Hello World" back. It seems silly but in my case it actually has an application where I can only parse my original string when it's reversed so after it's parsed I need to undo the reverse.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, you want to *extract method*:

```
 static string ReverseString(string value) {
   if (null == value)
     return null;

   var array = value.ToCharArray();

   Array.Reverse(array);

   return new string(array);
 }
```

Then you can easily *play* with the method:

```
 string original = "Hello World";
 string reversed = ReverseString(original);
 string reversedTwice = ReverseString(reversed);

 Console.WriteLine($"Orginal        : {original}");
 Console.WriteLine($"Reversed       : {reversed}");
 Console.WriteLine($"Reversed again : {reversedTwice}");
```

Outcome:

```
Orginal        : Hello World
Reversed       : dlroW olleH
Reversed again : Hello World
```